# Clarification on second derivative from Deep Learning textbook

Tags: quadratics, curvature

In Goodfellow et al.'s *Deep Learning*, the authors write on page 83:

> Suppose we have a quadratic function (many functions that arise in
>   practice are not quadratic but can be approximated well as quadratic,
>   at least locally). If such a function has a second derivative of zero,
>   then there is no curvature. It is a perfectly flat line, and its value
>   can be predicted using only the gradient

I'm confused by this statement because the second derivative of a quadratic function must be a nonzero constant. What did the authors mean by this statement? Also, what is the "it" they are referring to in "it is a perfectly flat line"? If it is the quadratic function, how can its value be predicted using only the gradient when the curvature is nonzero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general quadratic function is $$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad f(x) = x^T  M x + v^T x + a$$ for some matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, v \in \mathbb{R}^n, a \in \mathbb{R}$. The gradient is $\nabla f(x) = (M+M^T) x + v$ and the ([matrix of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix)) second derivatives is $\nabla \nabla f(x)=\nabla \nabla f(0) = M+M^T$.

If $\nabla \nabla f(0) = 0$  then $f$ was indeed linear and $f(0),\nabla f(0)$ is enough to compute $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes sense. I guess the authors just wrote it in a confusing way since a function with second derivative zero is not quadratic function and they did not mathematically state $f(x)$ as you did.

Comment: @VivekSubramanian A function is quadratic iff all its second derivatives are constant

Comment: Interesting, so all constant and linear functions are also quadratic?

Comment: @Vivek Yes. Linear and constant functions are also quadratic functions.